# Is there some way to show bending/folding deformation on a surface due to another object?

Tags: animation, add-on, physics

I have a platform that moves in a clockwise direction throughout the animation. then, another object needs to come down into frame and touch this object, dragging itself across it, which creates deformations on the surface as well as a permanent cylindrical divot. I can simulate the divot pretty easily by animating an expanding cylinder on the platform and making it invisible while also adding a boolean modifier. I've tried using soft body physics for the deformations before but it never seems to work. I apologize if this post seems like its missing details, but I cant share much as this is part of a research project. Any pointers?

Comment: Could you please share some drawings at least? Apart from Soft Body you have Cloth simulation or even you could fake the simulation with some shapekeys

Comment: See if [this](https://youtu.be/iblxdwwkjDc?t=537) tutorial by PIXX0 3D helps. I've set the start position to where he is describing setting up Dynamic Paint. To leave the displacement, just don't check Dissolve on the Canvas setting.